# Error while using translate() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to delete all punctuation marks from a sentence in python, but when i use this code:

```
 myString.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

I get the error:

> *translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)*

and I couldn't solve the reason for the error.

Comment: That's the syntax for Python 2.x - are you using Python 3.x per chance?

Comment: @Jon Clements: yes I am using Python 3.x

Comment: More specifically, that's the syntax for byte strings.  Unicode on python2.x wouldn't work here either, and byte-strings on python3.x do work (provided that you encode `string.punctuation` with the `'ascii'` codec ...)

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34294398/797495

Comment: Shucks... Had a cross-version answer ready but then the question was closed

Comment: @PedroLobito !  Thanks works great now!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you @Pela647 !

Comment: @PedroLobito But now i have additional problem-  I have done as the above stackoverflow link suggests, but if there was no space between the punctuation mark and the word, the output becomes, one joined word; for example; input: " i am,a" , output: "i ama" instead I want the output to be "i am a".

Answer (score 0):

Remove all punctuation from a string:

```
import string
transtable = {ord(c): None for c in string.punctuation}
strp = line.translate(transtable)
strp
```

Example:

Input : "Hey, Lets check this out!?"

Output : 'Hey Lets check this out'