# TypeError: translate() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, nltk, stemming

I found this python code to perform stemming on text files.

```
import nltk
import string
from collections import Counter


def get_tokens():
    with open('/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/Test_sp500/A_09.txt', 'r') as shakes:
        text = shakes.read()
        lowers = text.lower()
        no_punctuation = lowers.translate(None,string.punctuation)
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(no_punctuation)
        return tokens


tokens = get_tokens()
count = Counter(tokens)
print
count.most_common(10)

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

tokens = get_tokens()
filtered = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
count = Counter(filtered)
print
count.most_common(100)

from nltk.stem.porter import *


def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed


stemmer = PorterStemmer()
stemmed = stem_tokens(filtered, stemmer)
count = Counter(stemmed)
print
count.most_common(100)
```

When I try to run this program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/stemmer.py", line 15, in <module>
    tokens = get_tokens()
  File "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/stemmer.py", line 10, in get_tokens
    no_punctuation = lowers.translate(None,string.punctuation)
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Now my questions are:

1. How can I fix this?
2. When this program works, how could I run this script not only for one .txt file but for all the .txt files in a certain directory?

Note: I usually don't have to program so I only know the absolute Python Basics.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you're using a Python version >= 3.

In Python 2.7 the function `translate` [take 2 arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) but in python 3 and newer it [takes only 1 argument](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate). That's essentially why you're getting an error.

I am not sure what you're trying to do with the `None` argument, because in Python 2.7 it wouldn't make any sense anyway, you are basically trying to translate the `string.punctuation` in `None`.

Instead you would need to [make a translation table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294398/10400050) and then pass it to the translate function.

```
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
no_punctuation = lowers.translate(translator)
```