# How to use NLTK tokeniser on text with quotation marks?

Tags: nltk, tokenize, double-quotes, single-quotes

NLTK's tokeniser is acting very strangely when I try to tokenise a text with quotation marks in it.

I have a `.txt` file like this:

```
This text has some "quotation marks" to really 'make things' difficult.
```

I've written this python script to read the file and tokenize the text.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

with open("test_file.txt", encoding='utf-8') as test_file:
    test_text = test_file.read()

print(word_tokenize(test_text))
```

I would have expected (or, at least, hoped for) a result like this, where the quotation marks are treated like punctuation characters:

```
['This', 'text', 'has', 'some', '"', 'quotation', 'marks', '"', 'to', 'really', "'", 'make', 'things', "'", 'difficult', '.']
```

Instead this gives a weird result:

```
['This', 'text', 'has', 'some', '``', 'quotation', 'marks', "''", 'to', 'really', "'make", 'things', "'", 'difficult', '.']
```

Specifically, the tokens representing the quotation marks seem odd, as they're all represented differently to each other:

```
['``', "''", "'make", "'"]
```

The double quotes are changed into different characters, and the first of the single quotes is connected to the following word token, while the second becomes a separate token on its own. Maybe this is expected behaviour, but it's making a mess when I try to get the indexes of tokens within the overall string because ``` '``' ``` and `"''"` are two characters, whereas `'"'` is just one.

I've tried escaping the quotations in various different ways before applying tokenization:

```
if '"' in test_text:
    test_text = '\"'.join(test_text.split('"'))
```

and

```
if '"' in test_text:
    test_text= '\\"'.join(test_text.split('"'))
```

I've also tried embedding the string in triple quotes before tokenization:

```
test_text= f"""{test_text}"""
```

In the end I just wrote the following script to reverse the changes made by NLTK's tokenizer, and to separate the single quote from the following word token, all after tokenizing the string:

```
token_list = word_tokenize(test_text)
token_list = [tok if tok not in ["``", "''"] else '"' for tok in token_list]
for toknum, token in enumerate(token_list):
    if len(token) > 1 and token[0] == "'":
        token_list = token_list[:toknum] + [token[:1], token[1:]] + token_list[toknum + 1:]
```

This solution seems really janky though. Is there any more elegant way to get the quotation marks to be treated like any other punctuation characters?

Comment: do you want to keep the punctuation during tokenization? Perhaps you can get rid of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547409/how-to-get-rid-of-punctuation-using-nltk-tokenizer

Comment: @Raptor I need to keep the text, including punctuation, unchanged so that I can produce a list of token indexes. I can index the tokens if they stay the same as they are in the original string, but if they change, their indexes do too, and this creates inaccuracies.

Comment: how about extracting the quotes from sentences first, and manually adding them to the tokenizer?

Comment: You mean replace them with some other character? That's kind of what the NLTK tokeniser is already doing. It also comes with the downside that whichever character I replace them with can't be used in a text that I feed into the tokeniser. I guess there's no built-in way to change the character that replaces quotation marks in the NLTK tokeniser? If not then what I'm doing already kind of achieves the same end.